# How to increase agora sound quality

Tags: javascript, agora.io

Is there any way to get quality higher than 48kbs for audio stream in agora?
I am using

```
rtc.localStream.setAudioProfile("high_quality");
```

for local stream.
And the next config for recording

```
const json = {
                    Recording_Dir: `${storeFolder}`,
                    isAudioOnly: 1,
                    isMixingEnabled: 1,
                    audioProfile: 2
                };
```

But anyway, the output .aac file has a low bitrate (48)
What am I missing?

Comment: is the issue with the recorded audio or the audio in the stream?